Why are philosophers so unrespected and have so little influence
I was reading an ancient book (written about a thousand years ago) discussing various philosophical  and theological issues. The religious participant in the conversation made the observation that society as a whole does not perceive and respect  philosophers as people of higher morals and ethics. Nor do they  care about their conclusions when it come to personal moral and ethics.
At first that struck me as a surprising position to take  but upon thinking about it, the observations seem correct even today, a thousand years later. E.g. Very few Americans who don’t have an interest in philosophy would know or care about who heads the philosophy department in a place like Harvard. Even fewer would care about what he thinks or consider him personally to be some sort of moral icon. Furthermore I cannot think of a single voluntary initiative for the public good that was either  started by a group of philosophers who were looking to make the world a better place or came about as  result of their influence.
My question is: why is it that way?

I doubt that many Americans consider anybody a moral icon, they are more into pop-idols. Or that philosophers have particularly higher morals and ethics than other professions. But there are initiatives like Philosophers for Sustainability and Minorities and Philosophy. European philosophers are more socially active and some, like Habermas, are even media hyped as icons.

It's true that most Americans do not have moral icons but from those who do, they are usually either religious figures or people who (they believe) have devoted themselves to  helping others. No one seems to feel that way about philosophers

Or about mathematicians, lawyers, painters. Devoting oneself to helping others correlates with being a moral icon much better than any particular profession unrelated to charity. If this is the measure of influence and respect then philosophers are no better or worse than others.

Hi Schmerel, is your question specifically concerned with philosophy in the USA and should answer be focused on the USA as well?

Philosphers don't make anything, including money. They sit around discussing angels-on-the-head-of-a-pin type material, and write papers about it to each other. The best known philosophers, to the public, are from hundreds of hears to millennia ago. So as far as the general population goes, philosophy is just a past version of science. A contemporary philosopher's distant predecessors already did all the best, important work in laying down the underpinnings of western thought, and that's that.

"Very few Americans who don’t have an interest in philosophy..." - you've basically just said that people who don't care about philosophy, don't care about philosophy, which is trivially true.
The reliable and practical parts of philosophy has split off into science and maths, and what remains involves a lot of disagreement and a general lack of clear, tangible and practical results for the rest of society (even if philosophy itself might be important for understanding and refining what we believe and why).
So that's why modern philosophy has little influence, whereas the very idea of valuing science and modern ideas of human rights are built on the backs of philosophers of the past, via e.g. the enlightenment.
Also, you mention knowing the heads of philosophy departments, but how many people know the heads of science departments? Knowing that just isn't useful information for most people, and the only scientists the general public tend to know about are ones that make notable discoveries, who somewhat-separately built up some public image, or who happened to hold a prominent medical advisory and spokesperson role in government during some sort of global pandemic.
Given the lack of notable discoveries in and influence of modern philosophy (as mentioned above), it's unsurprising that there are fewer philosophers that are household names than there are scientists like Einstein or Hawking.
But most people have probably at least heard of some philosophers of old, like Plato. And there are certainly a few fairly-well-known modern philosophers like Daniel Dennett (one of the "four horsemen" of "new atheism"), Peter Singer (a notable figure in animal rights advocacy and utilitarianism) and Judith Butler (a fairly-well-known figure in feminism). Depending on how broadly you define philosophy, you could potentially add a lot of names in there, of well-known people who argue for various ethical or metaphysical positions.

As for trying to make the world a better place in the modern day, why would people do that under the very broad label of philosophy or exclude non-philosophers?

Philosophers who advocate for animal rights typically call themselves vegans or animal rights advocates.
Philosophers who advocate for women's rights typically call themselves feminists.
Philosophers who advocate for humans rights more broadly typically call themselves humanists.
Etc.

They would still be philosophers, but the thing they're advocating for is not just broadly philosophy, but those other things.
One could add "... and they associate and work with other vegans, feminists or humanists". But one might argue that those ideas themselves fall within philosophy, or are a result of philosophy (at least in part).

"The reliable and practical parts of philosophy has split off into science and maths" - this is a really good point, "natural philosophy" was what they called science before science, so it's not unreasonable for philosophy to take credit for at least some of the modern relevance and success of science.

Seperate the reliable & the practical, & we are what is left!


society as a whole does not perceive and respect philosophers as
people of higher morals and ethics

Well, they aren't. See The moral behavior of ethics professors (paper in the journal Philosophical Psycology).
The Life You Can Save and the Effective Altruism approach came out of the work of Australian philosopher Peter Singer as well as a couple of other thinkers. The movement for animal rights was powerfully influenced by his book Animal Liberation, and he was part of starting a movement to give enhanced rights to chimpanzees and dolphins. His 'Drowning Child' thought experiment in his book Famine, Affluence, and Morality has be a widely referenced touchstone for discussing moral reasoning. He is also a professor of bioethics now rather than philosophy, working on areas of applied ethics in medicine and biology. The richest man on Earth describes himself as influenced by the Effective Altruism approach, this is not niche.
Sartre, Camus and de Beauvoir were celebrities not just in France during their lifetimes, and beyond. Simone de Beauvoir's work The Second Sex is considered to mark the beginning of Second Wave Feminism.
Analytic philosophy, especially with formal symbolic logic, has had a tendency to retreat from culture, art, social change, and real world issues that matter to most people. Thinkers like Naom Chomsky and Slavoj Zizek show that there is still a place for public intellectuals to speak to a wide audience on philosophical issues, when they engage with culture and society.
I would describe the most important influence of philosophy not as providing settled answers, but in providing provocative questions. Trolley Problems are a great example of this.
The Ship of Theseus, the Chinese Room, the Simulation Hypothesis, these have become very widespread ideas, at least to people interested in relevant areas/topics. And specific phrases have permeated our language, Descartes cogito, Nietzsche's abyss, Kant's Categorical Imperative, Wittgenstein's 'Language is use', Camus' 'We must imagine Sisyphus happy'.
Philosophers are like writers. A tiny few become rockstars, most toil away in obscurity, and just occassionally one speaks to our moment in a deep way and shapes many lives. What's wrong with that?

The question of practicability is paramount. Manifestation is difficult.
Here, we speak of the ideals of philosophers such as the pure, simple, joyful and harmonious life, devoted to family, courage to fight scrupulous actions of others and the vision for future generations.
This is in contrast to the ego "I".
When I am doing archery, I can shoot a lot of arrows to see different strategies and adapt or learn a new strategy quickly. However, when I decide to build a house, there are many different tasks in this and I typically do not do all or many of them simultaneously. Instead, I assess which schedule is the most suitable.
We can consider numerous possibilities for undertaking any task, decision or major work. Though this may involve some cost, it is often not practical to evaluate all potential outcomes.
It is evident that there are significant constraints between the physical and mental planes of existence. It is therefore plausible to suggest that the majority of our lives are spent in a state of unconsciousness.

Probably the more conscious someone is, the more likely they would have the insight to agree with your last sentence. Let's see if you kick an anthill with that one.

In regard to the relative awareness between philosophers and theologians, that is mainly due to the fact that theologians are usually advocates for one or other denomination. Consequently they often engage with the public via accessibly written books that are often commented on by the media and clerics of their own faith.
The media seems to play a big role in the public awareness of philosophers: Sartre and de Beauvoir were also professional writers, as was Ayn Rand; Russell, Whitehead, Husserl and and Putnam were mathematicians; Hayek an economist; and many other 20th century notables were also psychologists, philologists, sociologists, etc. Having another string to one's bow - and the perspective that it gives - certainly seems to help in connecting to the wider public.
Your question does not distinguish between direct and indirect respect and influence of philosophers. If major political, bureaucratic or media figures in say UK or France (who would attend philosophy lectures when doing courses like PPE at Oxford or Sciences Po) are heavily influenced by a particular philosopher's ideas, we all may well be influenced indirectly by their decisions and opinions. So often - perhaps to add colour to dull characters - media people associate the the essence of political/administrative decision-making with the person applying it rather than the person whose ideas inspired it.
We should also make the point that in UK and USA, while religion (~ theology in a sense) is on school curricula, philosophy is not. This is unlike Spain, France, Brazil and other South American states. As such the vast majority of people in these countries are not attuned to philosophy, in fact they may well not even have a clear idea as to what philosophy really concerns itself with. In the UK of course - at least in England, Wales and N. Ireland - the A-level system removes any obligation by students to maintain study of subjects outside the 3 or 4 that they plan to take their final school exams in. UK students of physical sciences have little encouragement to widen their general knowledge in things like literature or humanities.
It's a bit unfair to single out philosophers as lacking "voluntary initiative for the public good" or not trying "to make the world a better place". It is no more a responsibility of philosophers to lead in such matters as it is of the rest of us mortals. Besides, when last did you take a scythe yourself and cut heavy weeds at your local graveyard ? When you did, did you specifically ask your fellow toilers if there was a philosopher amongst them ? You might be surprised to find that they too put in the odd shift for their communities.

I have a number of issues with your premises as well as your conclusions.

The Middle Ages were a deeply religious age. The world was considered God's creation, and the divine spark, being made in His image, was what set humans apart within that creation. If the conversation pits a theologian against a philosopher, the theologian's argument must concern the non-theological part. That part was relatively small and had little influence. Especially ethics without a religious foundation seemed and still seems impossible to the faithful.
The argument that philosophers don't heed their own advice applies at least equally to theologians, especially the Catholic ones.
A thousand years ago, "core" philosophy, theology, esoterics and natural sciences were all subsumed under the roof of philosophy. Indeed, most philosophers were polymaths, among them the greatest medieval ones, Albertus Magnus and Ibn Sina. Therefore, the theologian's argument may have well been directed against natural science and scientific medicine. The influence of the latter on our times cannot be overestimated; it is the last polymath, Leibniz, whose binary numbers in Explication de l'Arithmétique Binaire and calculus make your smartphone work. Our lives in the Western world are clearly shaped more by science (i.e., philosophy of nature) than by theology, an outcome the theologian certainly was unable to imagine.
The very foundation of the USA is as much a philosophical as a political act. The enlightenment separated God from king and put the individual with their right to the pursuit of happiness in the center. This is the philosophical underpinning of the French Revolution as well as the American constitution, and with that, essentially, of all of Western democracy. I'm not sure how much more influence you need.
On a smaller scale, ethical questions inform political debate every day. Political positions and political action in the refugee crisis, the Middle East conflict or the role of government are strongly informed by ethical arguments.

That the average American (or German, ...) cannot name many contemporary philosophers is unsurprising; many of us would have a hard time coming up with mathematicians or physicists either, even though they have an undeniable, profound influence on our lives. Probably close to nobody can name contemporary theologians.
But many people who know Einstein may know Gandhi; people who take an interest in political and sociological discussions may actually know a lot of philosophers whose ideas influenced the 20th century, like Nietzsche, Bertrand Russell, Ayn Rand, Wittgenstein, Chomsky, perhaps Derrida and Foucault, or the recently deceased Daniel Dennett.
Your medieval theologian was wrong.

Philosophy birthed the sciences... centuries ago.
What has philosophy (not the sciences) done for humanity lately?
We are as a species still stuck with religions and claims of human-consumerism-driven impending climate catastrophes.  And people believing in such.  Thats a philosophical fail, times two.
Philosophers are supposed to be leading thw charge to figure out the nature of knowledge and reality.

Source:  Stack Exchange Philosophy
Some are running around claiming "no-one cant know nuttin'!!"... and that they are the only smart ones, cause they are thus "enlightened".
We have "Consciousness makes reality".
We have matrix and simulator theories.
Gods, multiverses, know-nuttins, and simulation theorists...
... where is the part about figuring out reality?
Philosophers are supposed to be about figurong stuff out.  Supposed to be the capable competent advanced thinkers.  The sage mature critical analysts in the crowd.
Supposed to be.
But the question remains... since birthing the sciences... what has philosophy done?
Respect is earned.  Doesnt come free with an occupation or educational background.  (Some might think it should, which does not make it so).
NOTE:  That is not to say that philosophy has done little, or advanced little... it has within the sciences.  But when the sciences are treated as external to philosophy... then there isn't much room left for non-science based philosophy to make advances.

I agree that the 20th century seemed to produce failure and rubbish in Philosophy, but I don't know why people producing word-salad were so accepted? Maybe education fell apart after about 1950 or something.

@ScottRowe What happened to Europe post 1950. I guess after a near century it's America's turn now

@Rushi we're going to see an end to all the wars between the states when two non-north american nations meet in the capital?

@ScottRowe   Put the wrong link. Meant this

@ScottRowe And even the first link is better in this comment thread

@Rushi ok, I don't really watch video clips. If there is a transcript I'll read it. Video seems very intrusive, and requires either listening aloud where other people can hear, or rummaging for earphones. Subtitles would be a usable compromise, but then just provide a transcript.

@ScottRowe Summary version: Prof Jeff Sachs on the unfolding Ivy League University protests: Points out that it is Students Plus Faculty plus increasing nos of peaceniks vs. Donors plus Politicians plus other war-is‐good-business guys with the Univ admits caught in the crossfire.

@Rushi I agree that war needs to stop. But we have to find a way to stop the people who keep starting it. Conquering delusion would be the best approach, I think.

@ScottRowe Problem number one is peoples individual willing choice to pick up a gun and kill another if told it is justified and that they should do so.  Generals become impotent if the populations smarten up.

"What if they had a war and nobody came?" But many of the arguments for attacking others come from a religious base, that you have infinite existence, so your earth life is just a blip, but taking out the bad people becomes part of this infinitely large and important project. That delusion is responsible for a lot of recent trouble, and no generals are involved. Other kinds of hats are.
